# save output of a python script to a text file

Tags: linux, centos, unix, python, text

how can i save output of this python script to a text file? this is a KMS server which clients connect to it and activates their windows or office. i wanted to save the log in a text file. I should mention that the server is based on centos 7.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import argparse
import binascii
import hashlib
import random
import re
import socket
import SocketServer
import struct
import uuid
import rpcBind, rpcRequest

from dcerpc import MSRPCHeader
from rpcBase import rpcBase

config = {}

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("ip", nargs="?", action="store", default="0.0.0.0", help="The IP address to listen on. The default is \"0.0.0.0\" (all interfaces).", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("port", nargs="?", action="store", default=1688, help="The network port to listen on. The default is \"1688\".", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("-e", "--epid", dest="epid", default=None, help="Use this flag to manually specify an ePID to use. If no ePID is specified, a random ePID will be generated.", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--lcid", dest="lcid", default=1033, help="Use this flag to manually specify an LCID for use with randomly generated ePIDs. If an ePID is manually specified, this setting is ignored.", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--client-count", dest="CurrentClientCount", default=26, help="Use this flag to specify the current client count. Default is 26. A number >25 is required to enable activation.", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--activation-interval", dest="VLActivationInterval", default=120, help="Use this flag to specify the activation interval (in minutes). Default is 120 minutes (2 hours).", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--renewal-interval", dest="VLRenewalInterval", default=1440 * 7, help="Use this flag to specify the renewal interval (in minutes). Default is 10080 minutes (7 days).", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", dest="verbose", action="store_const", const=True, default=False, help="Use this flag to enable verbose output.")
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", dest="debug", action="store_const", const=True, default=False, help="Use this flag to enable debug output. Implies \"-v\".")
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--sqlite", dest="sqlite", action="store_const", const=True, default=False, help="Use this flag to store request information from unique clients in an SQLite database.")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--log", dest="log", action="store_const", const=True, default=False, help="Use this flag to enable logging to a file.")
    parser.add_argument("-w", "--hwid", dest="hwid", action="store", default='364F463A8863D35F', help="Use this flag to specify a HWID. The HWID must be an 16-character string of hex characters. The default is \"364F463A8863D35F\".")   
    config.update(vars(parser.parse_args()))
    # Sanitize HWID
    try:
        config['hwid'] = binascii.a2b_hex(re.sub(r'[^0-9a-fA-F]', '', config['hwid'].strip('0x')))
        if len(binascii.b2a_hex(config['hwid'])) < 16:
            print "Error: HWID \"%s\" is invalid. Hex string is too short." % binascii.b2a_hex(config['hwid'])
            return
        elif len(binascii.b2a_hex(config['hwid'])) > 16:
            print "Error: HWID \"%s\" is invalid. Hex string is too long." % binascii.b2a_hex(config['hwid'])
            return
    except TypeError:
        print "Error: HWID \"%s\" is invalid. Odd-length hex string." % binascii.b2a_hex(config['hwid'])
        return
    if config['debug']:
        config['verbose'] = True
    try:
        import sqlite3
        config['dbSupport'] = True
    except:
        print "Warning: Module \"sqlite3\" is not installed--database support disabled."
        config['dbSupport'] = False
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((config['ip'], config['port']), kmsServer)
    server.timeout = 5
    print "TCP server listening at %s on port %d." % (config['ip'],config['port'])
    server.serve_forever()

class kmsServer(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def setup(self):
        self.connection = self.request
        print "Connection accepted: %s:%d" % (self.client_address[0],self.client_address[1])

    def handle(self):
        while True:
            # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
            try:
                self.data = self.connection.recv(1024)
            except socket.error, e:
                if e[0] == 104:
                    print "Error: Connection reset by peer."
                    break
                else:
                    raise
            if self.data == '' or not self.data:
                print "No data received!"
                break
            # self.data = bytearray(self.data.strip())
            # print binascii.b2a_hex(str(self.data))
            packetType = MSRPCHeader(self.data)['type']
            if packetType == rpcBase.packetType['bindReq']:
                if config['verbose']:
                    print "RPC bind request received."
                handler = rpcBind.handler(self.data, config)
            elif packetType == rpcBase.packetType['request']:
                if config['verbose']:
                    print "Received activation request."
                handler = rpcRequest.handler(self.data, config)
            else:
                print "Error: Invalid RPC request type", packetType
                break

            handler.populate()
            res = str(handler.getResponse())
            self.connection.send(res)

            if packetType == rpcBase.packetType['bindReq']:
                if config['verbose']:
                    print "RPC bind acknowledged."
            elif packetType == rpcBase.packetType['request']:
                if config['verbose']:
                    print "Responded to activation request."
                break

    def finish(self):
        self.connection.close()
        print "Connection closed: %s:%d" % (self.client_address[0],self.client_address[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect script output to a file like this:

`/path/to/your/script.py > /path/to/your/log`

If you plan to execute the script multiple times and you want to append new outputs into the same log file, you can use:

`/path/to/your/script.py >> /path/to/your/log`

Comment: I used this command before in a systemd unit file but it does not create a log file

Comment: If it didn't create a log file, the script likely did not run. You'll need to do some testing, e.g., put "/bin/echo proof_of_concept > /path/to/your/log" in the systemd unit file. Then you'll know the unit file is working. The other option is to to write the log from the python script using the "open" command.